# Powershell script file is not executing from InstallShield CustomAction

Tags: powershell-3.0, installshield

I am getting below error, Please help

> InstallShield: Calling method with parameters [(System.UInt32)44,
>   (System.String)C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\230a078d-3d4a-48ad-bab4-b4f68aa7984d\CreateSelfSignedCertificate.ps1]
>   InstallShield: Loading Assembly
>   Microsoft.CertificateServices.PKIClient.Cmdlets InstallShield:
>   Couldn't resolve assembly by name
>   Microsoft.CertificateServices.PKIClient.Cmdlets InstallShield: Loading
>   Assembly Microsoft.CertificateServices.PKIClient.Cmdlets
>   InstallShield: Couldn't resolve assembly by name
>   Microsoft.CertificateServices.PKIClient.Cmdlets Action ended 0:49:26:
>   CreateCeatecert. Return value 1. Action ended 0:49:26: INSTALL. Return
>   value 1.

Comment: Are you using LaunchAppAndWait() function in InstallScript CustomAction to execute Powershell script file?

Comment: I tried above using Powershell custom action, it didnt worked then I tried LaunchAppAndWait(), 
c:\windows/System32/cmd.exe powershell.exe scriptfile.ps1
it worked for me